# cant align md-button to the left

Tags: html, angular, material-design, angular-material

Im using material design and I want a button to go left, so from what I saw I should add `layout-align` like this:

```
<button md-button (click)="someFunc()" class="md-primary" layout-align="end center">Sort</button>
```

but this didn't do the trick, do you see the issue?

Comment: `layout-align` controls how children are displayed. You may also need to learn how the different `flex` values work. Create a [mcve] demo for your issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding attribute layout-align, css will be applied to its children element.

So you can try this to place your button to left side

```
<div class="start" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
  <md-button ng-click="someFunc()"  class="md-primary">Start</md-button>
</div>
```